# why string with pipe with expand my div width

Tags: css

I have set a `<td>` to have a fixed width of `200px`. I am trying to put some text inside it, and I want the text to wrap to the next line. It seems to work okay, except if the string has pipes in it, when it won't wrap - it just expands the width of the `<td>`.

Here's my html:

```
    <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="d in t.dependencies">
              <td style="width: 200px">{{d.text}}</td>
              <td style="width: 120px">{{d.operator}}</td>
              <td>{{d.value}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the text I am using:

```
"ACCOUNTING_BUSINESS_UNIT|ACCOUNT|PROJECT|ACTIVITY_ID|RESOURCE|HOME_LOCATION|DEPARTMENT|something"
```

Comment: Please include some sort of code so we can see what you're trying to do

Comment: What means `with pipe with` ? There's a difference between `hello|world` and `hel|o world` you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
ACCOUNTING_BUSINESS_UNIT|ACCOUNT|PROJECT|ACTIVITY_ID|RESOURCE|HOME_LOCATION|DEPARTMENT|something
```

is a single word.

Words are splitted by blank spaces. You can solve that adding a css property:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

or also:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```